# jQuery mouseover/mouseout/click state image not working in IE6

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

I have an issue with IE6 not working to handle a 3 button state code.  I have to make this work in IE6 so just not supporting it isnt an option.

The code works in every browser I have tested in (FF3.6 PC and MAC, IE8 PC, Safari MAC) EXCEPT IE6 (PC).

Here is what the css is doing:

```
#button-1, #button-2, #button-3 {
         background-image: url('/images/inactive.png');
         background-position: top left;
}
.active#button-1, .active#button-2, .active#button-3 {
         background-position: top right;
}
.over#button-1, .over#button-2, .over#button-3 {
         background-position: bottom left;
}
```

then the jQuery:

```
$('#button-1).mouseover(function(){
    if($('#button-1').hasClass('active') == false){
        $('#button-1').addClass('over');
    }
});
$('#button-2).mouseover(function(){
    if($('#button-2').hasClass('active') == false){
        $('#button-2').addClass('over');
    }
});
$('#button-3).mouseover(function(){
    if($('#button-3').hasClass('active') == false){
        $('#button-3').addClass('over');
    }
});
$('#button-1).click(function(){
    changeTab(1);
});
$('#button-2).click(function(){
    changeTab(2);
});
$('#button-3).click(function(){
    changeTab(3);
});
```

The click state works fine in this context.  There is also a mouseout() similar to the mouseover but removing the 'over' class.

Of course there is more to and then its just a standard empty div element with an id of button-1 or whichever it is like

```
<div id="button-1">
    <div>Text</div>
</div>

<div id="button-2">
    <div>Text</div>
</div>

<div id="button-3">
    <div>Text</div>
</div>
```

When I invert the CSS classes like this (note the over class is now on top of the active class) :

```
#button-1, #button-2, #button-3 {
         background-image: url('/images/inactive.png');
         background-position: top left;
}
.over#button-1, .over#button-2, .over#button-3 {
         background-position: bottom left;
} 
.active#button-1, .active#button-2, .active#button-3 {
         background-position: top right;
}
```

In this instance, IE6 DOES do the rollover but DOES NOT do the click... It seems IE6 doesnt like switching between 2 classes on the same element... Not sure whats going on here and need some help on how to get the mouseover AND the click to work as they should.

I have firebuged it in Firefox and it is changing the classes as it should... I believe its doing it in IE6 but I think its something with CSS... Not so much the jQuery...

Oh, and I have tried adding an !important directive to the over classes' background position and that still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I thought IE6 does not handle multiple CSS selectors well? So it may be having problems with

```
.over#button-1
```

and so on.
This post seems to [explain how to get it to work in IE6](http://bytesizecss.com/blog/post/the-idclass-selector-in-ie6).

Comment: It doesnt work on background images... just colors... At least this confirms my findings that IE6 doesnt like multiple classes on the same ID